# How to use "greater-than" and "less-than" in db->get_where() in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm having a problem about my project. Because my logic wants something like

```
$this->db->get_where('products', array('prod_price' > 100 ));
```

So. I wan't to know if there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The custom operator should be part of the column's string:

```
$this->db->get_where('products', array('prod_price >', 100 ));
# Here --------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: So Im not going to use the '=>' anymore?